# Task using for (strcmp aswell)

Tags: c++

This is the code that I have now:

```
 int main() {
    char stupac1, stupac2;
    for (stupac1 = 'A'; stupac1 <= 'Z'; ++stupac1)
    {
        for (stupac2 = 'a'; stupac2 <= 'z'; ++stupac2)
              // between the caps and the non caps there are 32 letters (ASCII code)
              if(strcmp (reinterpret_cast <const char*> (stupac1),
                         reinterpret_cast <const char*> (stupac2)) == 32 )
              { 
                  cout <<stupac1 << stupac2 << endl;
              }
              else
              {
                  cout << "These letters suck" << endl;
              }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The task: I need to write a program with 2 consecutive loops that will make a table which has the letters A-Z and a-z in 2 columns.

I need to use `for`, but `strcmp` can be removed if is not necessary. I was trying something but nothing is printed when I run this code and it crashes.

Comment: Interesting, `strcmp` and `reinterpret_cast` on the same line...

Comment: Well not really, it's just a task from a book from which I'm learning C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single `char`s are just like a smaller version of `int`, so you can compare them or subtract their values, just like with `int`s.

A much simpler version of your test would be

```
if (stupac2 - stupac1 == 32)
```

See, much easier. :-)

Whenever you seem to need `reinterpret_cast` you are probably trying things the wrong way.

Comment: I added this, removed the else part and it works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In C++, characters (`char`) are scalar values just like `int`, not strings. For example `'A'` is equal to 65, assuming an ASCII/Unicode system. To test for equality, use the `==` operator.

It's quite easy to "count" from A to Z in ASCII, but not all C++ implementations are ASCII. For bonus points with your teacher, point out that the program wouldn't run under [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Also, before getting too accustomed to `char *` strings, be aware that real C++ programs almost exclusively use `std::string`, which also uses the `==` operator for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcmp (reinterpret_cast <const char*> (stupac1), reinterpret_cast <const char*>(stupac2))
```

This invokes undefined behavior, as the arguments to `strcmp` should be null-terminated strings, but what you're passing are not null-terminated.

Since it is not clear what you're trying to do, I'm not going to suggest an alternative *and correct* solution.

Comment: The task:I need to write a program with 2 consecutive loops that will make a table which has the letters A-Z and a-z in 2 colums.
So first column is:
A                           
B
C

2nd column is :
a
b
c


But it has to be together like this:

A a
B b
C c

Comment: `stupac1` isn't even an array of char -- it's just one char.

Comment: the for will generate everything from A-Z but i can't make this work properly.